# Sharepoint online (explorer view) .zip error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

I have a problem when opening a zip file.
It seems like when the file is larger than 100 Mb, I get this error:

[image]

It is in French but the error is "Error on compressed folders. Access to folder [Folder Path] denied."

Is this a known issue and if so, how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Does It work normally when you open a small zip file? Are you getting error when open it in Explorer view?

For narrowing down your issue, please try below things:

1. Download and check if you can open this file locally.

2.If the file opened previously, but now doesn't, there could be a problem with a corrupt file, or the format is not compatible with any of your apps. Make sure when you save a file, you try to open it to make sure it was saved correctly.

3. Test if you can open another zip file. Make sure if this error is related to your zip tool.

https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/fix-problems-opening-documents-in-sharepoint-libraries-31329fa1-4ad0-47fc-95d8-bb0c5b12a536

4. Check if there is another .zip file inside the issue zip file. If yes, split it out.

Comment: As I said, it works normally when I open a small file,
I have tried with 5 differents files (with no .zip inside)